# Expected: StringType, Found: INT32

Tags: azure, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

It's giving an error since I put typing, I put INT but I didn't know there was an empty field '', now I can't even select, how can I reverse this, I've tried to cast but it doesn't work

```
dfNewRecords = spark.sql("""

      cast(a.ped_pca as long) as ped_pca, 
      cast(a.transporte as long) as transporte, 
      cast(a.fornecimento as long) as fornecimento,
      cast(a.codigo_material as long) as codigo_material,

      from df_new  a
      where
      not exists ( select 1 from df_hist b
                   where
                      a.numero_nota_fiscal = b.numero_nota_fiscal
                      and a.centro = b.centro
                      and b.data_puxada between '{}' and '{}'
                      and a.codigo_material = b.codigo_material
                      and a.transporte = b.transporte
                      and a.cliente = b.cliente
                  )
      and (a.data_puxada <> 'Data Puxada' or a.data_puxada is not null)
   order by 5 desc""".format(date_ago,date_after)).repartition(16)
```

after I added typing, the following error appears: Parquet column cannot be converted. Column: [ped_pca], Expected: StringType, Found: INT32

Even making select without typing now only this error appears

Comment: You need to add more info. What are the data types for your table columns? Any special meaning for them?

Comment: can you post schema for df_new & df_hist ??

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue, after digging a least in my use case I had folder with parquet part files with same column having different types in different part.

Set `spark.sql.parquet.mergeSchema` to `true`

[Here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-parquet.html) is more details on Spark parquet read.
To resolve this for me, I deleted old schema part files because conversion wasn't possible (string to date)